# write redmine log from plugin

Tags: ruby, logging, plugins, redmine

I need to debug a redmine plugin because It doesn't work and we don't know why.

I don't know how to debug ruby from a remote server (I don't know ruby), so I need to modify the source of the plugin in order to put some plugin output in redmine logs.

How can I write a message in redmine log from a plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Redmine is a Rails application, you can use all the log facilities of Rails in Redmine and your plugin. Specifically, there is a global logger which you can use to log messages to the logfile (e.g. `log/production.log`):

```
Rails.logger.info 'My logged message'
```

See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger for more details about the Rails logger.

Note that in a production environment, Redmine logs only messages of level `info` and above. When starting your server with `RAILS_ENV=development`, Redmine also logs debug messages by default.